# JavaScript toString() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask how to convert the number to String.  What I want to output is "000000" incremented per second "0000001".  I tried different methods but it will output to 1,2,3... I tried this but still won't work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  xx();
  var x = 0;

  function xx()
  {

    x++;
    if(x.length==5) {
        x = "00000" + convert.toString(x);
    }

    $("div.sss").text(x);


    setTimeout(xx,1000);
  }

 });
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I see, the `xx` function is executed (the first time) BEFORE `x` is set to `0`.

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't declare named functions inside other functions. Not all interpreters like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
function padString(str, size) {
    str = "" + str;
    if (str.length >= size)
        return str;
    return "00000000000000000000000000".substr(0, size - str.length) + str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function xx()
{
    x++;
    str_x = "000000"+x;
    str_x = str_x.substring(str_x.length - 6);
    $("div.sss").text(str_x);
    setTimeout(xx, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
var x=00000+"";//convert number to string
for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
var y=x+"0000"+[i];
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(y);
}
</script>
```

check the link for live working example http://jsfiddle.net/informativejavascript/GmWYr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since `x` is `Number` is will not have a `length` property so `x.length==5` will always evaluate as `false` so your attempt to prefix it with a series of zeros will never be executed.

If it *was* executed, then it would fail because `convert` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use toString.  You can do `"foo" + x` or `"00000" + x` directly

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var x = 0;

 function loop() {
  var t = x + "";
  var n = 6 - t.length;

  while (n > 0) {
   t = "0" + t;
   n -= 1;
  }
  $("#foo").text(t);    
  x += 1;   
  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
 }

 loop();

});
```